# Is it possible to configure different JavaScript language versions for different files?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 2017.1.4 and I have a project which contains both ES5 and ES6 files at the same time. Therefore I want to configure syntax highlighting accordingly, but I'm unable to find how to do it :-(

So, the question is: how to configure JS version per file or, at least, folder?

Comment: JavaScript has backward compatibility, any syntax highlighter that works with ES2015 will also work fine with ES5.

Comment: Generally speaking -- not possible. Such functionality will be available in **2017.3 only**. In meantime -- have a look at possible suggestions in corresponding ticket -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12666

Comment: @adeneo, looks like my question wasn't verbose enough to explain what I want to achieve, sorry. I'm interested in separate rulesets for different language versions. For example I want to avoid warnings about `var` in ES5 files, but want to see corresponding `var`-to-`let` suggestions in ES6 files.

Comment: @LazyOne, thanks, can you create answer using your comment? I'd like to approve it. Also note on EAP will be acceptable too (I think 2017.3 should be accessible soon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, the question is: how to configure JS version per file or, at least, folder?

ATM it's not possible. But such functionality will be available in **2017.3**.

In meantime -- have a look at some possible workarounds in corresponding ticket (they might help in rather limited number of cases) -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12666.